# JavaFX TitledPane change background color at body and title

Tags: java, javafx

I try to change background color of TitledPane, but I don't know how.

I tried this `tpane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);");`, but don't work.

Comment: Take a look at the [substructure of `TitledPane`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane); maybe it will help.

Comment: @Slaw I tried, but I'm new with javafx and I still try to understand how customise works.

Comment: You can't use `setStyle` to target the title (You can but you have to look up the title in `Platform.RunLater`). You should use a CSS file: `.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-color: blue;}`

Comment: @trilogy can you give me a link of how to use it?

Comment: @trilogy I found it.

Comment: @KunLun what did you find?

Comment: How to use what you said. Using `Platform.runLater`, I change background like this `tpane.lookup(".title").setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);"`. Also, I don't know if this is a good way to change style or not.